# Hashmap contains key value

Tags: java

I want to get `containsKey` value in hashmap:

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
for (Contact ru : registered_users) {
    hm.put(ru.getPhone(), ru.getId());
}

if(hm.containsKey(c.getPhone())) {
    registered_phone_contacts.add(new Contact("", c.getName());
                                              ^^
    // Here I need to get value.
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You are supposed to get value from key and not key from value. That is not how HashMap works

Comment: yes.. There is only 1 key for that phone.

Comment: The only way is to maintain a reverse map (from value to key) yourself.  This is called a "bidirectional map" and is not a standard data structure in the JDK.

Comment: Ok.. I changed the question.. Now, is there any way to get value?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like that:

```
private String getKey(Integer value){
    for(String key : yourHashMap.keySet()){
        if(yourHashMap.get(key).equals(value)){
            return key; //return the first found
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or with stream api in java8 :

```
private Optional<String> getKey(Integer value){
    return yourHashMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(value)).map(e -> e.getKey()).findFirst();
}
```

It will works only if there are unique values for your keys...

Update:

There is BiMap in Guava - check out [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can either retrieve the value from the map in addition to the containsKey :

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
for (Contact ru : registered_users) {
    hm.put(ru.getPhone(), ru.getId());
}

if(hm.containsKey(c.getPhone())) {
    registered_phone_contacts.add(new Contact(hm.get(c.getPhone()), c.getName());
                                              ^^
  // value = hm.get(c.getPhone())
}
```

---

Or you can retrieved the value first and change the if to test the value instead of contains key :

```
<TypeOfId> id = hm.get(c.getPhone());
if(id != null) {
    registered_phone_contacts.add(new Contact(id, c.getName());

...                                           ^^
}
```

Hope that helps,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume phone numbers are guaranteed to be unique here, otherwise getting the associated ID for one doesn't makes sense. If so the simplest solution is probably just to build another hashmap with the reverse mapping using: `reverseMap.put(ru.getPhone(), ru.getId())`.

Then you can just do `revserseMap.get(c.getPhone());`.

From your example I don't see any need for the forward mapping once you have this reverse one, so you may just be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Just java 8.

```
Map<Long, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

final Contact c = ...;
Optional<Long> idOpt = hm.entrieSet().stream()
    .filter((e) -> e.getValue().equals(c.getPhone())
    .map((e2) -> e2.getKey())
    .findAny();
idOpt.ifPresent(id -> System.out.println(id));
long id = idOpt.orElse(-1L);
```